# Need to "DRY" up my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists, dry

So, i am using this carousel plugin which generates content which i can only interact with with javascript or jQuery.

So my problem is as follows. Underneath my carousel are bullets which have the following html:

```
<div id="bullets" class="jqarousel-ms-block">
    <ul>
        <li class="focus">0</li>
        <li class="focus">1</li>
        <li class="focus">2</li>
        <li class="focus">3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to target these li and increase the number inside of them by 1. 
so instead of 0,1,2,3 i want 1,2,3,4.

The code i have used is stupid since Its all repeat.

```
$("#bullets ul").children().eq(0).html(1);
$("#bullets ul").children().eq(2).html(2);
$("#bullets ul").children().eq(3).html(3);
$("#bullets ul").children().eq(4).html(4);
```

Help me DRY this up!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is needing a code review from codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an anonymous function to `html()` which you can use to amend the value. In your case, add `1` to the current value. Try this:

```
$("#bullets ul li").html(function(i, value) {
    return parseInt(value, 10) + 1;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/yn3jy6ax/2)

This method has the benefit of working should the numbers not start at `1`, or if the step is not a constant progression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#bullets ul li').each(function (i, obj) {
    $(this).html(i + 1);
});
```

Re-read and saw you want the number inside of it + 1:

```
$(this).html(parseInt($(this).val(), 0) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` to achieve this:

```
$("#bullets ul").children().each(function(i){
    $(this).html(i+1);
});
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zx53sc0e/) here.